# How to create/update Confluence page with Fabric python script set as Jenkins job

Tags: python, jira, fabric, confluence

I have to create/update confluence page with Fabric python script. We are using the Fabric scripts. I have to configured that script in jenkins. I have the Confluence REST API but how can I get all the information from Jira and update the confluence page If page is not exist then create and update the info on confluence page?

Comment: i read this twice , and despite the question mark , i think it's a broken statement @double-beep : "great editing"